# Sorting Google Chrome Bookmarks

Tags: sorting, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, bookmarks

Is there a way to sort Google Chrome bookmarks?

Sort on-save/periodically/on-demand by name/date-added.

According to google bookmarks API https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/bookmarks/
I can possibly add callback to `onCreated` method, which retrieves all the siblings and rearrange them.

Any help or design tips will be highly appreaciated.

Searching for extensions, browsing chrome extensions API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this.

```js
const bm = chrome.bookmarks
type BookmarkTreeNode = chrome.bookmarks.BookmarkTreeNode
type BookmarkDestinationArg = chrome.bookmarks.BookmarkDestinationArg

bm.onCreated.addListener((id: string, bookmark: BookmarkTreeNode ) => {
    let parent = bookmark.parentId!;
    bm.getChildren(parent, (siblings: BookmarkTreeNode[]) => {
        siblings.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title))
        siblings.forEach((sibling, index) => sibling.index = index)
        siblings.forEach(({ id, index}) => {
            bm.move(id, {
                parentId: parent,
                index: index,
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Full code: https://github.com/piotrpersona/bookmark-sort